# Is there any difference between catch lookup inner join reject and full outer join?

Tags: join, talend

I was reading about catch lookup inner join reject in Talend. From what I understood, catch lookup inner join reject picks up all the records which are rejected by the inner join. Doesn't this mean it is equivalent to full outer join?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same thing.

Doing a "Full outer join" in a query returns all rows from both joined tables: the ones that satisfy the join condition and those that don't.

"Catch lookup inner join reject" only returns the rows from your main flow for which there were no matching rows in the lookup flow. It's like doing a "left outer join", and getting only the rows from the table on the left side of the join for which there was no match in the table on the right side of the join.

Here's a [tutorial](https://community.talend.com/t5/Architecture-Best-Practices-and/How-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-a-Talend-batch-Job/ta-p/36394) if you want to do a full outer join in Talend.